# Spoof the mouse coordinates when sending/posting a message (GetMessagePos)

Tags: winapi

I'm posting the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`/`WM_LBUTTONUP` messages to simulate a mouse click on a specific location. That works most of the time, but there's one application which uses the `GetMessagePos` function to calculate the coordinates.

Is there any way to send/post a message with custom mouse coordinates?

Comment: Try using `SendInput()` to generate the input.

Comment: I believe that will work, but that will actually move the mouse on the screen. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684076(v=vs.85).aspx) to send the click instead of faking out the input stack.